# What does the symbol '^' after datatypes in C++ mean?

Tags: c++, class, types, parameters, symbols

when i stumbled upon some MS headers files... i found codes like this

`void App::OnSuspending(Object^ sender, SuspendingEventArgs^ args)`

yes a normal function header, but notice on the parameter declaration
"Object^", "SuspendingEventArgs^", i know they're somekind of classes but what is the use of "^" after each of them?

Comment: That's a totally different language [C++/CLI](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-372.htm)

Comment: You're looking at either C++/CLI or C++/CX code, and the `^` (hat) indicates that the type is a managed pointer.

Comment: It may also be C++/CX, in which case ^ is a "tracking reference".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

its not standard C++, its for compatibility with .net and signifies a .net reference type

Comment: Doesn't this denote a managed pointer? Or are those the same?

Comment: Well, of course, it means a reference. A reference points to a reference type, but it isn't a reference type itself; it is a value type. But I think anyone will get what you mean, so +1.

Comment: @Maurice : No, absolutely not - C++/CLI is an entirely separate language from C++. .NET introduced nothing to C++.